# UIImageView auto-created content size auto layout constraints overlap with trailing/leading constraints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I have a UIImageView (it's actually an FLAnimatedImageView). I use auto layout to set its constraints to occupy the entire screen. This works well in iPhone, but in iPad the auto-created constraints of the content (shown in the picture) cause it to take only some of the screen's size.

I don't understand why are these constraints created, and if they are indeed needed, why aren't the complying to the trailing/leading constraints?

[image: constraints]

[image: The image only taking some of the screen's size]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've googled the source of your view and found it at [GitHub](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage).
After looking into the implementation I found following code fragment:

```
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    // Default to let UIImageView handle the sizing of its image, and anything else it might consider.
    CGSize intrinsicContentSize = [super intrinsicContentSize];

    // If we have have an animated image, use its image size.
    // UIImageView's intrinsic content size seems to be the size of its image. The obvious approach, simply calling `-invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` when setting an animated image, results in UIImageView steadfastly returning `{UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric}` for its intrinsicContentSize.
    // (Perhaps UIImageView bypasses its `-image` getter in its implementation of `-intrinsicContentSize`, as `-image` is not called after calling `-invalidateIntrinsicContentSize`.)
    if (self.animatedImage) {
        intrinsicContentSize = self.image.size;
    }

    return intrinsicContentSize;
}
```

It seems that in case of animatedImage the size will be reduced to the original image size.

The apple documentation tells about intrinsic content size:

> In general, the intrinsic content size simplifies the layout, reducing the number of constraints you need

This can be interpreted as intrinsic content size usage already adds size constraints. For more informations about intrinsic content size usage see: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html)

One solution might be (not sure if there are some side effects) to use a subclass that overrides intrinsic content size like that:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, height: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric)
}
```

BTW: Please provide a link to the sources in next questions, it save us time searching for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whereas the accepted answer does provide a solution for these auto constraints not to be created, the problem causing my view to be cut was different.

I was doing view setup (not via storyboard) in `viewDidLoad`, but the view bounds changes do not take effect then.

Implementing that logic (e.g. adding views such as a progress bar in the center of the image view which rely on the image view's width) in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` gave me an entry point in which the constraints take effect and thus the UIImageView width is reported correctly view `frame.size.width` at that point.

From the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` official docs:

> When the bounds change for a view controller's view, the view adjusts the positions of its subviews and then the system calls this method

Source: [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews)